# I got error when i separate a single strCommandText into 3 strCommandText lines

Tags: c#, windows, forms, command

I got this error Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'join'. I guess i arranged it wrongly. It worked when it was in one line. I want to arrange it in 3 lines so it lo

Previous

```
string strCommandText = "SELECT appointmentID, aDate, aTime, aStatus, aContact, aHeight, aWeight, p.pFirstName , m.mcCentre , n.nFirstName FROM APPOINTMENT AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN Nurse AS n ON a.nurseID = n.NurseID Left outer join Patient as p on a.patientid = p.patientId left outer join medicalcentre as m on a.mcID = m.mcid";
```

After

```
string strCommandText = "SELECT appointmentID, aDate, aTime, aStatus, aContact, aHeight, aWeight, p.pFirstName , m.mcCentre , n.nFirstName FROM APPOINTMENT";
strCommandText += "AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN Nurse AS n ON a.nurseID = n.NurseID";
strCommandText += "Left outer join Patient as p on a.patientid = p.patientId";
strCommandText += "left outer join medicalcentre as m on a.mcID = m.mcid";
```

Comment: You may want to consider using the StringBuilder class, or better yet calling this as a stored procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a space to separate the text

```
    string strCommandText = "SELECT appointmentID, aDate, aTime, aStatus, aContact, aHeight, aWeight, p.pFirstName , m.mcCentre , n.nFirstName FROM APPOINTMENT ";
    strCommandText += "AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN Nurse AS n ON a.nurseID = n.NurseID ";
    strCommandText += "Left outer join Patient as p on a.patientid = p.patientId ";
    strCommandText += "left outer join medicalcentre as m on a.mcID = m.mcid ";
```

You could also remove the string concatenation using the verbatim prefix

```
    string strCommandText = @"SELECT appointmentID, aDate, aTime, aStatus, 
               aContact, aHeight, aWeight, p.pFirstName, m.mcCentre, n.nFirstName 
               FROM APPOINTMENT AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN Nurse AS n ON a.nurseID = n.NurseID
               LEFT OUTER JOIN Patient AS p on a.patientid = p.patientId
               LEFT OUTER JOIN medicalcentre AS m on a.mcID = m.mcid";
```

Comment: Beat me with 17 second `:)`

Answer (score 2):

You need spaces after every string you add.

Without spaces, your first concatenation seems like `FROM APPOINTMENTAS a LEFT OUTER` instead of `FROM APPOINTMENT AS a LEFT OUTER` which creates an invalid sql query.

```
string strCommandText = "SELECT appointmentID, aDate, aTime, aStatus, aContact, aHeight, aWeight, p.pFirstName , m.mcCentre , n.nFirstName FROM APPOINTMENT ";
strCommandText += "AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN Nurse AS n ON a.nurseID = n.NurseID ";
strCommandText += "Left outer join Patient as p on a.patientid = p.patientId ";
strCommandText += "left outer join medicalcentre as m on a.mcID = m.mcid";
```

You can have a multine string with using [`verbatim string literal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) like;

```
string strCommandText = @"SELECT appointmentID, aDate, aTime, aStatus, 
                        aContact, aHeight, aWeight, p.pFirstName, m.mcCentre, n.nFirstName 
                        FROM APPOINTMENT AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN Nurse AS n ON a.nurseID = n.NurseID
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN Patient AS p on a.patientid = p.patientId
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN medicalcentre AS m on a.mcID = m.mcid";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add space for every new string that you add to the command.

```
        string strCommandText = "SELECT appointmentID, aDate, aTime, aStatus, aContact, aHeight, aWeight, p.pFirstName , m.mcCentre , n.nFirstName FROM APPOINTMENT";
        strCommandText += " AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN Nurse AS n ON a.nurseID = n.NurseID";
        strCommandText += " Left outer join Patient as p on a.patientid = p.patientId";
        strCommandText += " left outer join medicalcentre as m on a.mcID = m.mcid";
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing spaces.  When you concatenate in the way you are doing it, it's easy to miss leading/trailing spaces. I'd use a stringbuilder rather than concatenating strings:

```
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.Append("SELECT appointmentID, aDate, aTime, aStatus, aContact, aHeight, aWeight, p.pFirstName , m.mcCentre , n.nFirstName From APPOINTMENT");
        builder.AppendLine("AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN Nurse AS n ON a.nurseID = n.NurseID");
        builder.AppendLine("Left outer join Patient as p on a.patientid = p.patientId");
        builder.AppendLine("left outer join medicalcentre as m on a.mcID = m.mcid");

        var commandText = builder.ToString();
```

Your current method will produce the following string:

```
SELECT appointmentID, aDate, aTime, aStatus, aContact, aHeight, aWeight, p.pFirstName , m.mcCentre , n.nFirstName From APPOINTMENTAS a LEFT OUTER JOIN Nurse AS n ON a.nurseID = n.NurseIDLeft outer join Patient as p on a.patientid = p.patientIdleft outer join medicalcentre as m on a.mcID = m.mcid
```

Notice the APPOINTMENTAS, n.NurseIDLeft and patientIdleft.  This is because of the missing spaces in your method of concatenation.